# How to handle anyarray parameterized stored function in batch execution with jooq (postgresql)?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have db schema like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.some_fun(anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS $$
  SELECT $1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE TABLE some_table (some_col int[]);
```

and I call the following code in java:

```
DSLContext ctx = ... // retrieve DSLcontext
Query query = ctx.insertInto(Tables.SOME_TABLE)
    .values((Field) someFun(new Integer[]{1}));
ctx.batch(query).execute();
```

the code produces an exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine
>   polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"

the produced query is:

> insert into "public"."some_table" ("some_col") values
>   ("public"."some_fun"('{"1"}'))

It turns out that jooq doesn't explicitely type cast the `{1}` array and postgres cannot infer the array type.

Interestingly, the following code produces the same query and does work:

```
Query query = ctx.insertInto(Tables.SOME_TABLE)
    .values((Field) someFun(new Integer[]{1}));
query.execute();
```

I guess this issue is related to how jdbc handles batch queries unless jooq logs diffrent queries to what it really executes. I found a hackish workaround for the problem using the following code:

```
Query query = ctx.insertInto(Tables.SOME_TABLE)
    .values(
        (Field) someFun(
            DSL.field(DSL.array(new Integer[]{1}).toString() + "::int[]")
        )
    );
ctx.batch(query).execute();
```

I have also tried to make jooq always explicitely type cast values by setting cast mode to `ALWAYS` but it seems not to work:

```
ctx.renderContext().castMode(RenderContext.CastMode.ALWAYS);
Query query = ctx.insertInto(Tables.SOME_TABLE)
    .values((Field) someFun(new Integer[]{1}));
ctx.batch(query).execute();
```

Do I really need to make type casting in the manual ugly manner or there is some better way to handle this?

---

UPDATE

It is possible to make the casting less frustrating by generating the type cast string like this:

```
String.format("::%s[]", DefaultDataType.getDataType(SQLDialect.POSTGRES, Integer[].class).getCastTypeName())
```

Still, it is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.8, PostgreSQL's `any`, `anyarray` and other polymorphic data types are not yet supported. There's a pending feature request for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5479

Your workarounds are probably as good as it gets right now.